# Quartz.net Setup Throwing Error: "onfiguration parser encountered <job>"

Tags: castle-windsor, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, sharp-architecture

I have a Asp.net C# MVC 3 application implementing the Sharp Architecture.  I have been trying to get Quartz.net to setup and work nicely with Castle Windsor for a few days without any luck.  Based on what I know, I have setup everything correctly, but continue to have issues.

In my **Global.cs** file, creating my Container and trying to register quartz jobs:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter("quartz_jobs.xml"));
container.AddFacility("quartznet", new QuartzFacility());
```

In my **quartz_jobs.xml** file I have the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quartz xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            version="1.0"
            overwrite-existing-jobs="true">
<job>
    <job-detail>
        <name>DeleteLoansWithoutClientsJob</name>
        <job-type>EasyOptions.Web.Mvc.Code.Jobs.DeleteLoansWithoutClientsJob, EasyOptions.Web.Mvc</job-type>
        <durable>true</durable>
    </job-detail>
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>DeleteLoansWithoutClientsJobTrigger</name>
            <group>MyJobs</group>
            <description>A description</description>
            <job-name>DeleteLoansWithoutClientsJob</job-name>
            <job-group>MyJobs</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</job>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you're pointing Windsor to the Quartz.NET config file.

There are two separate configurations: Windsor's and Quartz.NET's. Windsor is usually configured with code nowadays (i.e. fluent config), though it still supports XML configuration. However the Quartz.NET facility doesn't currently support code config, you have to use Windsor's XML config (at least for this, other components/facilities may still be configured via code). Then there's Quartz.NET, usually configured via an external quartz_jobs.xml file.

I recommend using the [Quartz.NET facility sample app](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/QuartzNetIntegration/tree/master/SampleApp) as reference. In particular, here's the [sample Windsor config](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/QuartzNetIntegration/blob/master/SampleApp/App.config) and the [sample Quartz.NET config](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/QuartzNetIntegration/blob/master/SampleApp/quartz_jobs.xml).

EDIT: if Quartz.NET says it can't find quartz_jobs.xml in a web application you need to include the web root in the configuration path: "~/quartz_jobs.xml" (instead of plain "quartz_jobs.xml")

Comment: When I remove the "quartz_jobs.xml" from the XmlInterpreter, it does not work... it gives this error: "File named 'quartz_jobs.xml' does not exist."  Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: @Reaction21 : use the sample app as reference.

Comment: @Reaction21 are using a suitable app.config / web.config with the facility config, as the sample app shows?

Comment: I am following the instructions based on the site to a T.  The Windsor Config registers the Quartz components, then I call container.AddFacility("quartznet", new QuartzFacility())  When it gets to the scheduler = sf.GetScheduler(); line in QuartzNetShceduler it fails with this error: "File named 'quartz_jobs.xml' does not exist."  Even though this file does exist.  I can run the sample app and it works fine, but for some reason, it does not like my app.

Comment: @Reaction21 : add this to your quartz configuration: `<item key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames">~/quartz_jobs.xml</item>`

Comment: Yeah I was able to find that a few minutes ago.  Dang that was difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post on how to integrate Quartz.NET with an IoC container. My example code uses Castle Windsor.

The blog post can be found here: http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.com/2012/02/integrate-quartznet-with-your-favourite.html

Comment: There's been a contrib project to integrate Quartz.NET and Windsor for 3 years now, please see http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/03/windsor-facility-for-quartznet.html and https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/QuartzNetIntegration . It supports a lot more than just managing jobs. Let's avoid the fragmentation of work efforts and work on this contrib project.